# C# - Base64 encoded JPEG to Base64 encoded BMP

Tags: c#, base64

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(in);
Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytes));
MemoryStream objMS = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(objMS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.MemoryBmp);
string out = Convert.ToBase64String(objMS.ToArray())
objMS.Close();
```

The code above fails with a very unhelpful error message:

```
'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: encoder'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shoudn't use `ImageFormat.MemoryBmp`, that's only for representing bitmaps in memory. There isn't any encoder for saving that as a file.

Use `ImageFormat.Bmp`.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
image.Save(objMS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.MemoryBmp);
```

To

```
image.Save(objMS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

*PS: Also `string out = ...` should be `string @out = ...`* (`out` is a c#'s keyword)